# how to set a tolerance to my event handler android

Tags: android, gps, numbers

I'm trying to make a GPS Android app and am having trouble setting a destination point.
 all the program does at the moment is grab your GPS location, and display your Latitude and Longitude, I want the app to tell you when you have reached a certain Latitude or Longitude but the coordinates don't stay at a steady number so I can never get the event to happen for more then a second before the coordinates change, I think I need the event to happen between two different coordinates, one being higher then the target coordinates and the other being lower but I can't figure out how to do that, someone please help

Comment: Current GPS technology on phones will most likely not be accurate to a specific lat/long for a long time. You must implement a valid "area", in order to detect that you've arrived.

Answer (score 0):

Specify a broader area that you'll accept.

```
if(lat > TARGET_LAT - 0.02 && lat < TARGET_LAT + 0.02 && lon > TARGET_LON - 0.02 &&  lon < TARGET_LON + 0.02){
    // close enough!
}
```

See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aWikiProject_Geographical_coordinates#Precision) for an idea on what the numbers should be.